# SQLite Android Count Query does not work

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on my capstone project which is developing an Android mobile application.
The application shows a survey questions, where the user let other people to answer it. The answers are stored in an SQLite database table. I succeeded in creating the database, taking input from radio buttons, and storing the answers into the table persistently. 
Each column in the table represents a question's answer.

Now I need to perform a `COUNT` query to count how many answers in each column with a specific criteria.

Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(KEY_GENDER)
FROM TABLE_ANSWERS
WHERE KEY_GENDER = "Female";
```

In the above query, `KEY_GENDER` is the gender column, the stored data is either female or male.
`TABLE_ANSWERS` is the table name.

This query's function is to show to show many females had answered the survey.

The following is the count query code snippet, which is located in a database class:

```
   // count of gender.
    public int countGender(){

        String colName = "COUNT(" + KEY_GENDER +")" ;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT" + colName + "FROM" + TABLE_ANSWERS + "WHERE" + KEY_GENDER + "=?" + new String[] {"Female"}, null) ;


        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int  colID = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_GENDER);
            int colID2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(colName);

        }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();

    }
```

Here is another snippet where the query is supposed to show the number of both "male" and "female" using group by:

```
 // count of gender.
    public int countGender(){

        String colName = " COUNT(" + KEY_GENDER +") " ;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
       // Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + colName + "FROM " + TABLE_ANSWERS + " WHERE " + KEY_GENDER + "=?" + new String[] {" Female"}, null) ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_GENDER + colName + "FROM " + TABLE_ANSWERS + " GROUP BY " + KEY_GENDER, null) ;


        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int  colID = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_GENDER);
            int colID2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(colName);

        }
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();

    }
```

The following snippet is the onCreate method in the Validation Results Activity class that should query the table TABLE_ANSWERS using the count method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_validation_results);

   DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(ValidationResults.this);
   TextView gender;
   gender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewGender);

    int genderResult;
    genderResult = db.countGender();

    gender.setText(String.valueOf(genderResult));

}
```

The catlog:

```
10-31 15:31:19.666    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 68K, 5% free 3410K/3556K, paused 13ms, total 16ms
10-31 15:31:19.754    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4% free 3628K/3780K, paused 83ms, total 83ms
10-31 15:31:19.770    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 6.030MB for 2536932-byte allocation
10-31 15:31:19.826    2221-2230/arwa.conceptsurvey D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 6106K/6260K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
10-31 15:31:20.686    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
10-31 15:31:20.690    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb93f2f40, tid 2221
10-31 15:31:20.774    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
10-31 15:31:20.774    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
10-31 15:31:21.022    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey W/EGL_genymotion﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
10-31 15:31:21.022    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
10-31 15:31:21.038    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
10-31 15:31:21.062    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
10-31 15:31:21.066    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
10-31 15:31:21.066    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
10-31 15:31:21.086    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-31 15:32:41.710    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 109K, 3% free 6992K/7172K, paused 10ms, total 11ms
10-31 15:32:41.738    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "SELECTCOUNT": syntax error
10-31 15:32:41.738    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-31 15:32:41.738    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cfab20)
10-31 15:32:41.750    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: arwa.conceptsurvey, PID: 2221
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{arwa.conceptsurvey/arwa.conceptsurvey.ValidationResults}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECTCOUNT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECTCOUNT(gender)FROMAnswers
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECTCOUNT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECTCOUNT(gender)FROMAnswers
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
            at arwa.conceptsurvey.DatabaseHandler.countGender(DatabaseHandler.java:211)
            at arwa.conceptsurvey.ValidationResults.onCreate(ValidationResults.java:27)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 15:32:44.474    2221-2221/arwa.conceptsurvey I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 2221 SIG: 9
```

The problem is: whenever I press the button that navigate to the Validation Results Activity to show the query result, the app stops and shows this message: "Unfortunately, the app has stopped" and obviously doesn't show any count query results.

When I take off the database code from the Validation Results Activity, the activity works well with a blank page of course since it does not contain any code. So, I think the main problem is from the count query only.

I got the structure of those queries from a textbook called Android Database Programming.
I also tried to change the structure and t other things to make it work.
I've been searching the web and textbooks to solve the problem and get the count query to work.

So, what is the problem in my count query? how can I make it work and shows the results?
I would really appreciate your help since I have to submit this project so soon.

Thank you in advance.

Update: I had a syntax problem with spacing the SQLite keywords.I fixed it in the code above by adding spaces to the keywords.

Comment: Spacing is your problem, You just need a space. It should be "FROM Answers", or "SELECT COUNT". It cannot read "FROMAnswers" or "SELECTCount"

Comment: question is offtopic: `This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced **or a simple typographical error.** While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. `

Comment: sheesh.  Read the error message?

Comment: Is your SPACE key broken?!

Comment: @Jawascript I did add spacing, but still it doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: @Selvin Sorry for the disturbance. I don't have much experience in stack overflow since it is my first question here. Thanks for informing me.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike Yes I read it. Actually I just started learning and implementing Android programming 3 weeks ago. So I am a newbie and I tried to understand the logcat messages but couldn't really do that. Thank you.

Comment: @Funkystein I fixed the spacing. The problem still unsolved. Thank you.

Comment: As you can see from the LogCat, this **was** your problem: `SELECTCOUNT(gender)FROMAnswers`. If now you fixed it, it should read, correctly: `SELECT COUNT(gender) FROM Answers`

Comment: @ArwaA. Getting good at reading and understanding error messages is one of the best skills a n00b can acquire

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see on your log

```
"SELECTCOUNT": syntax error (code 1):
```

Add spaces after your `SELECT` word:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT "
```

the same goes for `FROM` and other reserved words like `WHERE, GROUP` etc

Comment: He's correct, you need to make sure you are adding spaces manually

Comment: @Pedro Oliveira Yes the SQL keywords had no spacing. Now I fixed it and added spacing, but the query still not working. What could be the root problem? Thank you.

Comment: Update your question. If the problem is not SQL related mark this as answer and start a new post.

Comment: @PedroOliveira I updated it. I am working on the code to make sure whether it is an SQLite problem or not. If it is not, I will mark this as answer. Regards,

Comment: There are still spaces missing...`olName + "FROM " + TA` add spaces BEFORE the reserved keywords aswell